# How to break out of a lexical mode

Tags: antlr4

I've been playing around with modes in an attempt to parse a message like this:

```
-MSGTXT (DO NOT TOKENIZE (THERE CAN BE PARENS HERE) THIS PART)
-END END OF MESSAGE
-TEST 123
```

The contents of MSGTXT can be any character so I set up my lexer grammar as follows:

```
lexer grammar ADEXPLexer;

// Fields
MSGTYP: 'MSGTYP';
ADEP: 'ADEP';
TITLE: 'TITLE';
FILTIM: 'FILTIM';
ORIGINDT: 'ORIGINDT';
IFPLID: 'IFPLID';
MSGTXT: 'MSGTXT' -> pushMode(MSG);
COMMENT: 'COMMENT';

// Message types.
ACK: 'ACK';
IFPL: 'IFPL';

// Lexical rules.
SEP: HYPHEN;
WS: [ \t\n\r] + -> skip;
KEYWORD: (ALPHA|DIGIT)+;

mode MSG;
  TEXT: CLOSE_MSG | (ALPHA|DIGIT|SPECIAL|WS|HYPHEN)+;
  CLOSE_MSG: ')' -> popMode;

fragment HYPHEN: '-';
fragment ALPHA: [A-Z];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment SPECIAL
  : '('
    | '?'
    | ':'
    | '.'
    | ','
    | '\''
    | '='
    | '+'
    | '/'
    | ')'  
  ;
```

The problem now however is that the last closing ')' is never used to break out back into the default mode so it continues on into other parts of the message. The parser rule itself looks like this:

```
msgtxt: SEP MSGTXT TEXT;
```

I'm looking for a way to get around this which doesn't involve TokenStreamRewriter as there's no such thing in the JavaScript runtime.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is there a guarantee that parentheses will be nested correctly?  (i.e. is "( text (more)" valid?

Comment: BTW, TokenStreamRewriter wouldn't be a solution even if you had it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to check if contents of the `TEXT` is one of the `(ALPHA|DIGIT|SPECIAL|WS|HYPHEN)` just use this:

```
mode MSG;
  TEXT: ~[)]+;
  CLOSE_MSG: ')' -> popMode;
```

if you do, just exclude `')'` from `fragment SPECIAL`